# Why col in Bootstrap starts in a new line?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I hove following Grid:

```js
<StyledContainer>
  <StyledRow>
    <StyledCol lg="6">
      <div
        style={{
          height: "30px",
          width: "1px",
          borderLeft: "1px dashed #fff",
          display: "inline-block",
        }}
      ></div>
    </StyledCol>
    <StyledCol lg="6">
      <img
        src="/sendmade-logo-white.png"
        alt="Sendmade logo"
        width="120px"
        height="40px"
        id="logo"
        style={{
          margin: "24px 32px",
          padding: "10px 10px",
          borderLeft: "1px dashed #fff",
        }}
      />
    </StyledCol>
```

Tried with and without `display: "inline-block",` in `div`, but somehow `div` always break line. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you overriding any of the `row` properties ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a react problem, as those tags are not standard. It would be worth adding that to the list of tags.

That said, I have created a JSFiddle with an approximation of that code to show that bootstrap is in fact not at fault here...
https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/paojLvqc/7/

```
        <StyledContainer>
      <StyledRow>
        <StyledCol lg="6">
          <img
           src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/2048px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
           alt="Sendmade logo"
           width="120px"
           height="40px"
           id="logo"
           style="margin: 24px 32px; padding: 10px 10px; borderLeft: 1px dashed #fff;"/>
        </StyledCol>
        <StyledCol lg="6">
          <img
           src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/2048px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
           alt="Sendmade logo"
           width="120px"
           height="40px"
           id="logo"
           style="margin: 24px 32px; padding: 10px 10px; borderLeft: 1px dashed #fff;"/>
        </StyledCol>
      </StyledRow>
```